# How do I add publish dates to uploaded files in Typo3?

Tags: file, date, typo3, publish

I am currently maintaining a client's existing Typo3 6.1 site and one of the things they would like to add to their site is the possibility of applying publish and expiration dates on uploaded files, in the same way such dates can be applied on Typo3 pages.

I did some research on the matter to see if something like this had already been done before. I tried looking for existing Typo3 extensions on Google and on the official Typo3 extensions repository that would add this functionality, but nothing like this seems to exist. I also tried to find ways of doing it myself, still without any results.

What would be the best approach to add this functionality to a Typo3 6.1 website?

**EDIT**

After some investigating, I noticed another extension was already hooked up with the TCEForm of the file editing page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/up7mO.png

In this screenshot, you can see I managed to add the start and end datetime fields as the first two fields in the form ("Date de publication" and "Date d'expiration"). I currently have the following configuration in my `ext_table.php`:

```
<?php

if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
        $_EXTKEY, 'Documents', 'Documents'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Documents');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::loadTCA('sys_file');
$newFileColumns = array(
    'date_publication' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.date_publication',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 13,
            'max' => 20,
            'eval' => 'datetime',
            'checkbox' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
            'range' => array(
                'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'date_expiration' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.date_expiration',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 13,
            'max' => 20,
            'eval' => 'datetime',
            'checkbox' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
            'range' => array(
                'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'desactive' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'config' => array(
          'type' => 'passthrough'
        )
    ),
    'isbn' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.isbn',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 50,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ),
    ),
    'auteurs_internes' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.auteurs_internes',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
            'MM' => 'tx_documents_document_auteur_mm',
            'size' => 5,
            'maxitems' => 10,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'wizards' => array(
                'suggest' => array(
                    'type' => 'suggest',
                    'default' => array(
                        'searchWholePhrase' => 1
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'auteurs_externes' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.auteurs_externes',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 50,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ),
    ),
    'responsable' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.responsable',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'db',
            'allowed' => 'tx_common_domain_model_unitelogique',
            'size' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'wizards' => array(
                'suggest' => array(
                    'type' => 'suggest',
                    'default' => array(
                        'searchWholePhrase' => 1
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'type_document' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.type_document',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.tx_common_type = "type_document" ORDER BY sys_category.title ASC',
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'minitems' => 1,
            'renderMode' => 'tree',
            'treeConfig' => array(
                'parentField' => 'parent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'public_cible' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.public_cible',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
            'MM' => 'tx_documents_document_publiccible_mm',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.tx_common_type = "public_cible_document" ORDER BY sys_category.title ASC',
            'maxitems' => 100,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'renderMode' => 'tree',
            'treeConfig' => array(
                'parentField' => 'parent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'important' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.important',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'check',
        ),
    ),
    'nouveau' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.nouveau',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'eval' => 'date'
        ),
    ),
    'misajour' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.misajour',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'check',
        ),
    ),
    'no_magistra' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.no_magistra',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 50,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ),
    ),
    'centre_documentation' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.centre_documentation',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'check',
        ),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.image',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'size' => 1,
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/pics',
            'disable_controls' => 'list',
        ),
    ),
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file', $newFileColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file', '--div--;LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.tab, date_publication, date_expiration, isbn, auteurs_internes, auteurs_externes, responsable, type_document, public_cible, important, nouveau, no_magistra, centre_documentation, image');

// Edit of existing fields
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::loadTCA('sys_file');
$TCA['sys_file']['columns']['title']['config']['placeholder'] = '';
$TCA['sys_file']['columns']['title']['config']['eval'] = 'required';
$TCA['sys_file']['columns']['title']['config']['size'] = '50';

$TCA['sys_file']['columns']['description']['config']['wizards'] = array(
    'RTE' => array(
        'icon' => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
        'notNewRecords' => 1,
        'RTEonly' => 1,
        'script' => 'wizard_rte.php',
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext.W.RTE',
        'type' => 'script'
    )
);
$TCA['sys_file']['columns']['description']['defaultExtras'] = 'richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts]';

// Add category types
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::loadTCA('sys_category');
$TCA['sys_category']['columns']['tx_common_type']['config']['items'][] = array('LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:category.type.type_document', 'type_document');
$TCA['sys_category']['columns']['tx_common_type']['config']['items'][] = array('LLL:EXT:the_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:category.type.public_cible_document', 'public_cible_document');
?>
```

However, defining the columns as start and end access dates with

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file']['ctrl']['enablecolumns']['starttime'] = 'tx_myext_starttime';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file']['ctrl']['enablecolumns']['endtime'] = 'tx_myext_starttime';
```

as suggested in the answers makes the file list show an error instead of loading a list of files. Instead, I tried using the $TCA variable to define them. The error page shown by Typo3 is not shown anymore using this, but the editing page still can't be rendered successfully.

The $TCA configuration I added:

```
$TCA['sys_file'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'label' => 'title',
        'label_alt' => 'name,description,alternative,identifier,uid',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'versioningWS' => 2,
        'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,
        'origUid' => 't3_origuid',
        'enablecolumns' => array(
            'disabled' => 'desactive',
            'starttime' => 'date_publication',
            'endtime' => 'date_expiration',
        )
    )
);
```

The following image shows what happens with this $TCA configuration added while trying to edit a file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VaCD.png

The TCEForm is simply not rendered and I don't know why. I'm not sure if my configuration in `ext_tables.php` contains a bad configuration (especially in the $TCA config I added) or if the problem comes from another file in the extension.

What can be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAL (File Abstraction Layer) does not have a `starttime` and `endtime` field.

But since the `sys_file` related tables (like `sys_file_reference`) can be extended by your own extension and TCA offers you the `starttime`/`endtime` functionality by default my biggest guess will be that this can be accomplished with some modifications in the TCA.

Here a quick kickstart of how you can try to extend `sys_file` with the `starttime` and `endtime` fields.

**ext_emconf.php**

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array (
    // more stuff here in between
    'constraints' => array (
        'depends' => array (
            'filelist' => '6.1.0-6.1.99',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**ext_tables.sql**

```
#
# Table structure for table 'sys_file'
#
CREATE TABLE sys_file (
    tx_myext_starttime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tx_myext_endtime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
)
```

**ext_tables.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

$tempColumns = array();
$tempColumns['tx_myext_starttime'] = array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 13,
        'max' => 20,
        'eval' => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => 0,
        'default' => 0,
        'range' => array(
            'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
        ),
    ),
);

$tempColumns['tx_myext_endtime'] = array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 13,
        'max' => 20,
        'eval' => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => 0,
        'default' => 0,
        'range' => array(
            'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
        ),
    ),
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file']['ctrl']['enablecolumns']['starttime'] = 'tx_myext_starttime';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file']['ctrl']['enablecolumns']['endtime'] = 'tx_myext_starttime';

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file', $tempColumns, 1);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file', '--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, tx_myext_starttime, tx_myext_endtime');
unset($tempColumns);
```

I don't know if the FAL persistence layer and repositories does support (or better: eat) this configuration and I can't estimate in which kind of problems you're gonna run. But I guess it's a try worth.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried your solution and it does add two new fields in the sys_file table. As this is only one part of the problem I am facing, I am now wondering how I can fill these two fields directly from the upload page of the File List plugin. Can you give me some tips on how to achieve this? You can look at my edited question for more details.

Comment: Since there are multiple ways to upload files (like uploading from 3th party extensions, fal drivers, ...) you might look to some kind of 'general solution' for your approach. My suggestion will be some kind of back-end module which can do the upload start / endtime thing.

Comment: I think that extending the `sys_file_reference` table for instance is a better approach to set up some start and ending times since that does not affect the file itself self only the relation between the file and the content.

The approach where you start/endtime the `sys_file_reference` will be easier to understand for editors, and probably even visible in a standard back-end environment (with this I mean the icons).

Comment: It looks like there already was an extension defined for the file uploading in the fileadmin. I added the start and end fields in this one instead. I have a problem with using the default TCA `starttime` and `endtime` with this though. See my updated answer once again for more information. Thanks again for your help.